# Installing and Debugging Prestashop Module in NetBeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, installation, prestashop-1.6

I have installed Prestashop module in my local and placed my prestashop folder in apache server htdocs folder.

It is working fine, when i run it in local (localhost:8090/prestashop/index.php).

I'm trying to study code from prestashop to create a new module.

so I installed it in netbeans (project taken from apache server htdocs folder).

from netbeans, it runs perfectly but i can't debug it.

Please help to debug it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Befor some one help you to configure xdebug or other there is one good way to debug with some changes in **config/deines.inc.php**:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

.....

define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);
```

So after that you can see some useful debug information and a lot information like MySQL strings, classes, files and etc. It will help you to understand.

Hope it helps you a little.